# How to download a certain version of a package?

Tags: apt, ppa, libraries

I tried `sudo apt-get install package-name=1.23`, but apparently it is not available for this version of Ubuntu...?

I get:

```
E: Version '1.23 for package-name' was not found.
```

Do I need a command line option to force it to install this version?

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphical method:

Using Synaptic, select the package you want to install, then select *Package → Force version* from the menu; the shortcut binding "Ctrl+E" will also work. In the newly opened window, choose the version you wish to install and apply the changes from the main window.

If the version you wish to install does not appear in the list, update the package database and try again. If you are installing a version from a PPA, make sure the package index successfully updates the index for the PPA.

Command-line method:

The command you used seemed to have correct syntax. However, it is most likely that the version you type is either incorrect or incomplete. You might be missing a revision number: for example, for a version x.y.z-r, the r would be the revision number, preceded by a dash. Sometimes this revision number has the name "ubuntu" in the middle, depending on the package you install. In this case, the version you want to install might be called "1.23-1" or "1.23-1ubuntu0" or something around that, although the version would be commonly referred to as 1.23.

To find the correct version number, you can use `aptitude versions package-name` in a terminal. It will print out all available versions for the package, mention its status (eg. i for installed, p for available in the repositories). Then you can look for the version you are looking for and use it in your command instead of 1.23.

Comment: What is Synaptic? I get aptitude is not installed. Are these instructions for Ubuntu? 14.04.1?

Comment: Synaptic is not included with Ubuntu since a few versions, but you can download it from the Ubuntu Software Center or with `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. Aptitude should be present by default, but if it is not, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install aptitude`. Otherwise, you can look for your package's version(s) on packages.ubuntu.com for regular packages and on Launchpad for PPAs.

Comment: Actually, your comment about "1.23-1ubuntu0" was the key. They moved the words around between releases! Thank you.